# How to create multiple PDF files using PDF API2?

Tags: perl, pdf

Below is complete minimal code required to create a single PDF file using Perl module PDF::API2. The first PDF is created fine. At the start of the attempt to create the second PDF, the process fails at the second instance of line:

```
  $page = $pdf->page(0);
```

with the error, `Can't call method "new_obj" on an undefined value at C:/Perl64/site/lib/PDF/API2/Basic/PDF/Pages.pm line 92.`

Why? More importantly, what change do I have to make to create a second pdf?

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use PDF::API2;

  my $pdf1 = 'hello_world.pdf';
  my $pdf2 = 'hi_mom.pdf';
  my $text1 = "Hello World";
  my $text2 = "Hi Mom";
  my $pdf = PDF::API2->new();       #dynamic pdf file name
  my $font = $pdf->corefont( 'Times-Roman',   -encoding => 'latin1' );

  my $page = $pdf->page(0);
  $page->mediabox( 612.0, 792.0 ); #8.5" x 11.0" in PostScript points
  my $msg_text = $page->text;
  $msg_text->transform(-translate =>[72, 144]); #x,y position in points
  $msg_text->fillcolor('black');
  $msg_text->font($font, 100);
  $msg_text->text($text1);
  $pdf->saveas($pdf1);

  print "Make 2nd pdf.\n";
  $page = $pdf->page(0); #FAILS!
  {..}
  $msg_text->text($text2);
  $pdf->saveas($pdf2);
  print "2nd pdf created\n";

  $pdf->end();

  1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Data::Dumper` after first creating `$pdf` reveals a lot of data:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'catalog' => bless( { } )
             # Lot lots more, including:
             'pdf' => $VAR1->{'catalog'}{'Pages'}{' outto'}[0],
             # Which is referenced several times, e.g. $self->{pdf}->new_obj(...)
           }, 'PDF::API2' );
```

This is all removed after the call to `saveas`, causing the `undefined value` error:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {}, 'PDF::API2' );
```

You could recreate `$pdf`:

```
$pdf = PDF::API2->new();
```

but then you'd also need to add all the other method calls (`corefonts`, `mediabox`, `text`). Easier to put the PDF creation code into a sub:

```
sub create_pdf {
    my $name = shift;
    my $text = shift;

    my $pdf = PDF::API2->new();
    ....
    $pdf->saveas($name); # also calls end()
}
```

Then call it twice with relevant arguments.

```
create_pdf($pdf1, $text1);
create_pdf($pdf2, $text2);
```

Full working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDF::API2;

my $pdf1 = 'hello_world.pdf';
my $pdf2 = 'hi_mom.pdf';
my $text1 = "Hello World";
my $text2 = "Hi Mom";

create_pdf( $pdf1, $text1 );
create_pdf( $pdf2, $text2 );

sub create_pdf {
    my $name = shift;
    my $text = shift;

    my $pdf = PDF::API2->new();       #dynamic pdf file name
    my $font = $pdf->corefont( 'Times-Roman',   -encoding => 'latin1' );

    my $page = $pdf->page(0);
    $page->mediabox( 612.0, 792.0 ); #8.5" x 11.0" in PostScript points
    my $msg_text = $page->text;
    $msg_text->transform(-translate =>[72, 144]); #x,y position in points
    $msg_text->fillcolor('black');
    $msg_text->font($font, 100);
    $msg_text->text($text);
    $pdf->saveas($name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Naturally, I'll proceduralize my code. The second call to `PDF::API2->new()` does not solve the problem. The error changes to `Can't call method "val" on an undefined value at C:/Perl64/site/lib/PDF/API2/Resource.pm line 69.`. Anyway, creating a new instance of the PDF class should not be required to creat a new page (or so I would hope). (Normally, I would dv an answer that does not even work. But I appreciate the help and besides, perhaps I'm doing something wrong in applying your solution? Do you know it works? If not, I suggest deleting it.)

Comment: I assume that calling `saveas()` finalizes the internal object, and makes it unusable for further use. The documentation does not say so, but maybe this is just an omission.

Comment: Great, thank you @RobEarl. I think maybe @Slaven Rezic is right that after `saveas()` returns, the object is destroyed, though, if that is the case, I'm surprised that the error does indicate an undefined method call. PDF::API2 is wonderful, but is good use a little more documentation, IMO. (Maybe I'll read the source and post back here my findings.)

Comment: @Karl, I had a quick look at the source, `saveas` does call `end` but the documentation isn't entirely clear on what that does

Answer (score -2):

```
if($lineas_pag == 160){  
    $page2 = $pdf->importpage($old, 2);
    $page2->mediabox('Letter');  
    my $msg_text = $page2->text;
    my $font = $pdf->corefont( 'Arial-Bold',   -encoding => 'latin1' );                
    $msg_text->font($font, 8);    
    $txt=  $msg_text;
} 
$txt->translate(96 ,$lineas_pag); $txt->text( " HOLA " );
```

Comment: Try to format your code and perhaps a word of clarification is required too. Indent the code four spaces to create a code block.

Comment: Good answers provide an explanation.